# Как авторизоваться в google contacts API?

Tags: python, авторизация, google-contacts

Я использую библиотеку [`gdata`](https://github.com/dvska/gdata-python3) (тут ссылка на репозиторий неофициальной версии библиотеки `gdata-python-client`, поддерживающей Python 3). Сначала я пытался авторизоваться так:

```
gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='Export contacts to Google')
gd_client.ClientLogin('google_login', 'google_password', gd_client.source)
```

Но получил ошибку

> `ClientLoginFailed: Server responded to ClientLogin request: 404, b'https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps\n'`

Я [погуглил](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps) и насколько понял возможности авторизоваться с помощью логина-пароля нет с 20.04.2012.

Тогда я попробовал авторизоваться следующим образом (взятым [отсюда](https://pythonhosted.org/gdata/docs/auth.html)) –

```
next = ''
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']
secure = False  # set secure=True to request a secure AuthSub token
session = True
gdata.gauth.generate_auth_sub_url(next, scopes, secure=secure, session=session)
```

У меня получилось сгенерировать ссылку,

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fmyapp.py%3Fauth_sub_scopes%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fcontacts&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcontacts&session=1&secure=0&hd=default
```

но она переадресовывает на [support google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?visit_id=1-636639208138580672-3583348311&p=authsub&rd=3) (вне зависимости от того, что указано в `next` – http://www.google.com, http://www.example.com/myapp.py или пустая строка).

Затем я попробовал создать проект в Google API Console. Подключил API контактов, создал учетные данные, получил идентификатор клиента и секрет клиента.

Снова попытался авторизироваться –

```
client_info = {
    "client_id": "******-*************.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "***************",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
}

scopes = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'

gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(
        source='airtable2gcontacts',
        auth_token=request_token)

gd_client.get_contacts()
```

И снова получаю ошибку –

> `Unauthorized: Unauthorized - Server responded with: 401`

Больше идей у меня нет, что я делаю не так, как мне авторизоваться в google contacts API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил наконец проблему.

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('cred_json_file_from_google_api_console',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
                               redirect_uri='http://example.com/auth_return')
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url() #переходим по сгенерированной ссылке, переадресовываемся на страницу example.com/auth_return?code={code}
credentials = flow.step2_exchange({code})
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'
auth2token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=credentials.client_id,
  client_secret=credentials.client_secret,
  scope=scope,
  access_token=credentials.access_token,
  refresh_token=credentials.refresh_token,
  user_agent=None)
gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(
            source='airtable2gcontacts',
            auth_token=auth2token)
print(gd_client.get_contacts()) #все работает
```